# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress controller default page / redirect

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, infrastructure, nginx-ingress

I was wondering if there is a way to change the behaviour of the nginx ingress controller so that instead of a 404 page it displays another web page or does a redirect?
Sadly you can’t do

- host: “*”

To achieve the same thing since its not a valid subdomain definition.

Any help is much appreciated!

(Using the ingress controller from here: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller (Docker Image))

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a non-microservice world when you use nginx you have an option to land all of the HTTP requests on a host with a `default` listen flavor. Since the ingress controller in a k8s environment is basically still an nginx server with some additional functionality, you can do the same thing, but this time you'll have to customize the controller deployed.

See, the out-of-the-box controller still has this `default` functionality, and it's this very thing that provides the 404 page you're seeing. It's even explained [in the official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/).

There's a poorly documented approach described [here](https://medium.com/alterway/how-to-custom-your-default-backend-on-kubernetes-nginx-controller-9b38048e10c0), but I'd go with cloning and customizing the [upstream](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) itself.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering about this in the future:

You can define an Ingress like below to do a catch-all for the default nginx.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-name
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service-name
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: some support and references information would be nice to improve the answer. So others could prove that ;)